# Valums File Uploader Count Before Processing

Tags: ajax, file, upload, count

I'm using the Valums file uploader at the moment which works great, but what I want to do is modify it so it counts the number of files in the destination directory to check there's less than a specified number of files already in there before processing...

..So I thought I'd put a simple ajax function to do this check in the onSubmit bit (not sure of tech name for it) and return true or false (return false aborts upload process) depending on the result of the file count. What I'm finding is that this ajax call is getting aborted (according to FireBug) for some reason every time I go to upload a file with the error helpfully returned as "undefined".

What I'm wondering is if there's some quirk of the Valums uploader that won't allow a ajax call in the onSubmit bit....or am I just going about it wrong.

Code:

```
function createUploader(){

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    action: '/Scripts/FileUploader/server/uploadprocess.php',
    debug: true,
    multiple: true,
    autoUpload: true,
    dragDrop: true,
    params: {
        UpType: UpType,
        UpRef: UpRef,
        Thumb: Thumb
    },

            onSubmit: function(id, fileName){

                // --- This is my check that's getting aborted ----
                // --- Made this async because I want it do do this first, not sure if right though ---

                var NumFiles = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                url: "CountImages.php",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'text',
                data: "UpType=blaUp&UpRef=blaRef",
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {         

                        // --- Ajax failed ---
                            alert("Oh Dear: " + textStatus + " and errorThrow: " + errorThrown.Status);
                        // --- showing "Oh Dear: error and errorThrow: undefined" ---
                    }
                }).responseText;

                if (NumFiles === "False")
                {
                    return false;
                }

            },

            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){

                // Do stuff

            }
});
```

}

Any help greatly appreciated.
Dan

Comment: I want to achieve the same, can you share your CountImages.php?

Answer (score 0):

My stupidity. The URL of the script being called by the Ajax function was invalid. I expected this to error with a file not found type response instead of undefined.